# Finding distinct numbers in a range, given some step size

Tags: math, range, discrete-mathematics

I have been trying to come up with some mathematical formula to find the distinct numbers in a given range with a variable step size.

First I tried in 1-D, like in a range [0,10], with a step size of 0.1.
Solution: In between 0.1-1,1.1-2,.......,9.1-10. Every sub-range has 10 numbers, so total #=100. Including 0, we get 100+1=101.

Next is to find the total points in a grid (2D).
Solution: In a grid, with two axes x and y, we need to find the total # points. x is in the range [-10,10] and y in the range [-10,10], with a step size of 0.1.
With 2D it gets complicated, and in higher dimensions and with varying step size, it becomes really messy. I was just wondering if there is a generalized formula or method to find the points.

[Grid or the 2D space looks something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW31g.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not significantly more complicated in higher dimensions, because the optimal packing in higher dimensions is a grid. Suppose you have `x` in the closed range `[x1, x2]` in steps of `dx` and you have `y` in the closed range `[y1, y2]` in steps of `dy`. Just on the `x` axis, there are `1 + floor((x2 - x1) / dx)` values, and just on the `y` axis there are `1 + floor((y2 - y1) / dy)` values, so in the 2d grid there are

```
(1 + floor((x2 - x1) / dx)) * (1 + floor((y2 - y1) / dy))
```

distinct points.

This generalizes to higher dimensions (assuming `dx`, `dy`, `d...` are constant). So just find the number of distinct points in each dimension and multiply those values together to get the number of distinct points in the `n`-dimensional region.